# In Worksheet query results, why are some values highlighted blue?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, worksheet

When I run a query, some results are returned in blue, while others in regular black font.  Why?

[image: Snowflake Results Screen Capture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically see this when the field is very long (difficult to display from just extending the column length) and clicking the link allows me to see the entirety of the data in an easy pop-up.  Does this seem to fit the trend of what you are seeing?

Comment: that's exactly what it was.  Thank you Suzy.

Answer (score 1):

if the text/string is just text it mean it has newline/carriage returns in the data, or the other reason is it's of type variant, but then all of that column would be blue.. which implies the former.